# PHP doesn't work on Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: apache2, php

I've just got a Ubuntu machine (I'm usually a Debian user). I've installed apache2 and PHP using the below commands and restarted apache2 but when I visit the site the PHP doesn't execute (I just see all of the PHP code printed on the website).

`apt-get install apache2 php`

This is all that is required on Debian; are there further steps required on Ubuntu?

Comment: `sudo apt-get install php7.0-mysql php7.0-curl php7.0-json php7.0-cgi  php7.0 libapache2-mod-php7` should do it.

Comment: I've already installed apache2 and PHP. apache2 -v and php -v confirms.

Comment: First try to check PHP with this `php -r "echo 'hi';";`, if it's  working fine then reinstall `libapache2-mod-php` and enable php.

Answer (score 3):

You also have to install `libapache2-mod-php` (or `libapache2-mod-php7.0` if you have PHP7) and restart Apache if this doesn't happen during the module install.

Comment: It works for me on Ubuntu 16.04 with php7.