# PHP doesn't work after upgrade to 16.04

Tags: upgrade, apache2, php, php7

After the upgrade to Ubuntu 16.04, php files in the `public_html` directory are not processed anymore by `apache2`. If I browse some page `http://localhost/~myusername/index.php`, the php code is rendered as plain text.

It might be related to the upgrade to `php7.0`, which (I think) replaced `php5` in Ubuntu 16.04.

I already tried what is suggested in the following:

- [PHP rendered as text after Ubuntu 16.04 upgrade](https://askubuntu.com/questions/760787/php-rendered-as-text-after-ubuntu-16-04-upgrade)
- [user directory/public_html not working after upgrading to ubuntu 16.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/806623/user-directory-public-html-not-working-after-upgrading-to-ubuntu-16-04)
- [PHP and Apache2 broken after upgrade to Ubuntu 16.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/761705/php-and-apache2-broken-after-upgrade-to-ubuntu-16-04)
- [PHP doesn't work on Ubuntu 16.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/796460/php-doesnt-work-on-ubuntu-16-04)

Any idea about what might be wrong?

Comment: can you also post snippet of apache virtualhost configuration, will help in finding problem?

Comment: you can also reinstall apache and php if you do want to waste more time in debugging the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved reinstalling PHP, as follows.

```
sudo aptitude purge `dpkg -l | grep php| awk '{print $2}' |tr "\n" " "`
sudo apt-get install php7.0 php7.0-fpm php7.0-mysql libapache2-mod-php
sudo a2enmod php7.0
sudo service apache2 restart
```

I also edited the file `/etc/apache2/mods-available/php7.0.conf` in order to allow PHP in user directories (and then, again, restarted `apache2`).